# Got an unexpected OpenGL error, and have no idea what is causing the error nor how to fix it

Tags: python, sdl

I'm trying to make a chess program, this is supposed to show the board with the `tcod` module, but I can't even run this code, only edited some parts but everything else is from the website.
When trying to run the code I encounter this error:

> libtcod 1.16.0-alpha.15 libtcod/src/libtcod/renderer_gl2.c:196
> Unexpected OpenGL error.

Tried looking for a solution but can't find any for this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tcod
import chess

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 720, 480  # Window pixel resolution (when not maximized.)
FLAGS = tcod.context.SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | tcod.context.SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED


def engine(board) -> None:
    """Script entry point."""
    tileset = tcod.tileset.load_truetype_font(
        "chess.otf", 32, 8,
    )

    with tcod.context.new(  # New window with pixel resolution of width×height.
        width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, sdl_window_flags=FLAGS, tileset=tileset
    ) as context:
        while True:
            console = context.new_console(order="F")
            console.print(0, 0, str(board))
            context.present(console, integer_scaling=True)

            for event in tcod.event.wait():
                context.convert_event(event)  # Sets tile coordinates for mouse events.
                print(event)
                if event.type == "QUIT":
                    raise SystemExit()
                if event.type == "WINDOWRESIZED":
                    pass  # The next call to context.new_console may return a different size.


engine(chess.Board())
```

traceback:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    Vlákno 'MainThread' (0x1) skončilo s kódem 0 (0x0).
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\adamn\OneDrive\Plocha\Programování\Python\Chess-bot\engine.py", line 32, in <module>
    engine(chess.Board())
  File "C:\Users\adamn\OneDrive\Plocha\Programování\Python\Chess-bot\engine.py", line 21, in engine
    context.present(console, integer_scaling=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\tcod\context.py", line 217, in present
    self._context_p, console.console_c, viewport_args
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\tcod\_internal.py", line 63, in _check
    _raise_tcod_error()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\tcod\_internal.py", line 57, in _raise_tcod_error
    raise RuntimeError(ffi.string(lib.TCOD_get_error()).decode("utf-8"))
RuntimeError: libtcod 1.16.0-alpha.15 libtcod/src/libtcod/renderer_gl2.c:196
Unexpected OpenGL error.
```

Comment: Is there a full stacktrace you can post?

Comment: edited the post with full traceback

Comment: The error comes from `static TCOD_Error resize_textures(struct TCOD_RendererGL2* renderer, const TCOD_Console* console)` so something might be wrong with your textures. It is called from `context.present`. It is unfortunate that tcod won't reveal the actual error to Python. It should print the value of `glGetError()` at least. If possible for your application, run a pdb breakpoint and investigate what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, figured it out, apparently I can't have an otf font AND a resizable window